# Joint schengen visa interview with spouse possible?

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas

can I take an appointment for Schengen visa in the same time with my husband and stand for the interview together? Or we need to take appointment separately?

Answer (score 1):

The [VFS website for Denmark in India](http://dk.vfsglobal.co.in/Schedule_An_Appointment.html) has this to say:

> Please make sure you arrive at the visa application center 15 minutes prior to your appointment time. Applicants are not allowed to be accompanied inside the visa application center. The only exceptions to this are those accompanying children under 18 years-of-age or applicants who need special assistance for health reasons or disability.

And VFS is handling the visas. So, while I can't find anything on europa.eu where this information should be, the official answer seems to be: you need to take the interview separately.